# RSA key signing and verifying in Java(Android)

Tags: android, rsa, public-key

I am having a slight problem with understanding the concept of RSA signing and verifying.
The problem is that I can create key pair (public and private key) which is perfectly fine.

```
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        keyGen.initialize(2048, random);
        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        myPrivateKey = pair.getPrivate();
        myPublicKey = pair.getPublic();
```

Signing and verifying are as follows:

```
        //Singing with private key
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        s.initSign(javaPrivateKey);

        //Verifying with public key
        Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
        s.initVerify(javaPublicKey);
```

When I print myPrivateKey and myPublicKey, I see modulus(n) and public exponent(e) are the same for public and private key.

I have converted public and private keys to base64 and hex and I get the different values which is perfectly fine. However, I cannot sign the message with base64 or hex. I can sign it only with what I get from this:

```
         myPrivateKey = pair.getPrivate();
```

I am aware of that verifying needs to be done with the public key which is visible to everyone. When the message is verified by the receiver, does the receiver use modulus and exponent only? What part of the public key needs to be shared by the sender? Modulus and exponent or Base64 or hex value of the key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the receiver uses modulus and exponent only; there are no other components that are required mathematically speaking to verify a signature for RSA.

The mathematical operations are performed using large numbers (`BigInteger` values commonly when RSA is implemented in software). To perform any kind of calculation the implementation must regenerate these numbers. How these numbers are transmitted doesn't matter to the algorithm.

Commonly RSA public keys are encoded using something based on PKCS#1, which specifies the public key format using ASN.1 (which defines the structure) and BER/DER (which defines the encoding of that structure). Of course, different protocols may use different encodings of public keys. PGP for instance uses an entirely different "package format" to encode keys.

---

Java however returns a SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure which is defines in the X.509 (certificate and CRL) specifications; besides the modulus and exponent is also contains an algorithm identifier to show that it *is* an RSA public key. So this structure can also be used to distribute other kind of key values. It can be retrieved by calling `getEncoded()` on the `RSAPublicKey` instance - assuming that this instance is compatible with the Oracle provided one - they generally are. Android's implementations certainly should be compatible with this structure. Note that the SubjectPublicKeyInfo structure contains the PKCS#1 public key structure *inside of it*.

To reverse you need an `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")` and derive the key using `X509EncodedKeySpec`, initialized with the given byte array.

---

**If** you need textual strings instead of binary then you can convert the bytes returned by `getEncoded()` into base 64 and hexadecimals. Of course, in that case, you need to reverse the encoding (i.e. decode) the result before being able to decode the bytes themselves.

It is also possible to encode the modulus and public exponent yourself. You can retrieve them using `RSAPublicKey.getModulus()` and `RSAPublicKey.getPublicExponent()`. To reverse them back into an `RSAPublicKey` you can use `KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")` and `RSAPublicKeySpec`. That way you can for instance just create a string `"(<modulus>, <exp>)"` and use that to distribute the key. Generally you would want to keep to predefined standards though.

---

Not covered in this answer is the fact that to verify with a public key you first need to establish *trust* in the public key. If you cannot trust the public key then you don't know who created the public key. In that case you can also not trust the result of your verification operation; the signature may have been created with a key pair of an adversary. Delving into Public Key Infrastructures (PKI / PKIX) is a bit too much for this answer though.

Likewise: SHA-1 is not considered secure anymore, *especially* for signature generation / verification. You would want to use at least `SHA256withRSA` or - slightly more advanced and somewhat more secure - an RSA scheme that uses PSS. 2048 bits is ever so slightly too small for comfort; using a 4096 bit key is advisable if your scheme allows it.

Comment: I'll hopefully add some links later.

Comment: Thank you @Maarten Bodewes! This was a spot on answer, I appreciate it. I assume that to be able to establish the trust in the public key, I need digital certificate.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to establish trust, probably the most common one. You can also e.g. compare fingerprint ID's (hash over the modulus) over the phone or other out-of-band means.

Comment: Oh wow thank you @Maarten Bodewes! Fingerprint ID's would be really cool to implement in my app! I will definitely look into it.

Comment: when I sign the data with public key, to able to verify the data, the receiver needs to use the exponent and modulus. This is the part I perfectly understand. My question is that in what format do I share the public key? As encoded only or Base64 or hexadecimal format or do I share exponent and modulus only?

Is sharing exponent and modulus secure?

Comment: It doesn't matter much, as long as you clearly describe it and - as indicated - as long as you can trust the public key. Of course, it depends on who you want to share the public key and how you want to transport it. Maybe the other party would like to use e.g. PKCS#1 / PEM encoded public keys that are generated by e.g. OpenSSL. Possibly  the other party works with Java / Android and you use the default, SubjectPublicKeyInfo in binary format. In the worst case you may need to put the public key in a certificate. Ask them! If you share it with yourself, well, then you're completely free.

Comment: I am having a little of trouble with signing data. I am hashing the data and after signing it, and also I am encrypting the data. So my protocol looks as follows: "ServerPK+(data, UserPK-(hash(data)))". When I compare hashes, I fail to get the hashed data because I am signing it. Can I read the signed data, which is the "hash(data)" part? If not, how can I compare the hashes?

Comment: Also, when signing the data, I am creating  
Signature s = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
Does this mean that I am hashing with SHA256 and signing it together already?
Because I was trying to use Bcrypt for hashing and SHA256 for signing

Comment: The only way to compare hashes is to retrieve them from the signature currently, as the hashing is done internally as you might expect. You can use a cipher than then raw "decrypt" (perform modular exponentiation with the public exponent) to get to the hash, but you'd have to find it in the padding. You could use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/NoPadding")` for this, but it may not be supported. This is also specific to RSA / PKCS#1 v1.5 mostly. Java's API is not super flexible in this regard, you cannot retrieve the internal hash state.